# Divide values in rows by key/id in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataset

```
Key Measure     01/01/18 01/02/18 01/03/18 01/04/18 01/05/18
A   # of exams  121     130     115     120     123
A   # of people 1327    1326    1323    1323    1336
B   # of exams  124     132     110     118     125
B   # of people 1110    1115    1113    1116    1118
```

I want to divide and find **#of exams/#of people** for each key

Expected output:

```
Key Measure       01/01/18  01/02/18 01/03/18 01/04/18 01/05/18
A   # of exams/ppl  0.09    0.10    0.09    0.09    0.09
B   # of exams/ppl  0.11    0.12    0.10    0.11    0.11
```

Any thoughts?

**From the answer:**
I am trying to generalise to n unique keys:

```
keys_unique=df["Keys"].unique()
```

columns_unique-the number of date columns I have

```
ListOfSeries = []
for i in range(0,len(keys_unique)):
    ListOfSeries += [complete_data.iloc[:, 0:len(columns_unique)].iloc[2*i]/complete_data.iloc[:, 0:len(columns_unique)].iloc[2*i+1]]
dnew = pd.DataFrame(ListOfSeries)

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your DataFrame by doing :

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'Key' : ['A','A','B','B'], 'Measure' : ["# of exams","# of people","# of exams","# of people"],'01/01/18' : [121,1327,124,1110],'01/02/18' : [130,1326,132,1115],'01/03/18' : [115,1323,110,1113],'01/04/18' : [120,1323,118,1116],'01/05/18' : [123,1336,125,1118]})
```

and I obtained :

```
            01/01/18    01/02/18    01/03/18    01/04/18    01/05/18    Key Measure
0           121         130         115         120         123         A   # of exams
1           1327        1326        1323        1323        1336        A   # of people
2           124         132         110         118         125         B   # of exams
3           1110        1115        1113        1116        1118        B   # of people
```

You can obtain what you need to compute by doing something like :

```
listOfSeries = []
for i in range(0,2):
    listOfSeries += [dat.iloc[:, 0:5].iloc[2*i]/dat.iloc[:, 0:5].iloc[2*i+1]]
dnew = pd.DataFrame(listOfSeries)
```

Please note that my columns are not ordered like yours, so you should replace `[0:5]` by `[2:7]`. Here's the result :

```
    01/01/18    01/02/18    01/03/18    01/04/18    01/05/18
0   0.091183    0.098039    0.086924    0.090703    0.092066
1   0.111712    0.118386    0.098832    0.105735    0.111807
```

Now you simply need to add the extra columns you want (the non numeric ones). You can add columns by writing :

```
dnew['Key'] = pd.Series(['A', 'B'])
dnew['Measure'] = pd.Series(['# of exams/ppl', '# of exams/ppl'])
```

Since your columns are ordered, you can do it by hand without any loss of information or error. This gives you :

```
    01/01/18    01/02/18    01/03/18    01/04/18    01/05/18    Key Measure
0   0.091183    0.098039    0.086924    0.090703    0.092066    A   # of exams/ppl
1   0.111712    0.118386    0.098832    0.105735    0.111807    B   # of exams/ppl
```

Hope this solution suits you, and if you need complementary explanations, feel free to ask.

**-- EDIT --**

If you want to do it automatically with respect to the `Key` column, you can do something like :

```
listOfKeys = list(set(dat['Key'].values))
listOfSeries = []
for i in range(0,len(listOfKeys)):
    dtemp = dat.loc[dat['Key'] == listOfKeys[i]]
    serie = dat.iloc[:, 0:5].iloc[dtemp.index[0]]/dat.iloc[:, 0:5].iloc[dtemp.index[1]]
    serie['Key'] = listOfKeys[i]
    listOfSeries += [serie]
dnew = pd.DataFrame(listOfSeries)
```

This code finds all the different values of the `Key` column in `dat`. Then it finds the rows of `dat` where the value of `Key` is equal to a particular value, and divides the first row by the second one. As it can change the order of the rows (a set is not ordered), we need to add the `Key` column in the `for` loop to ensure that the `Key` still corresponds to the right row.

Comment: Can you please help me to understand how to add the extra columns(like in my case the key) to the result. Also in For loop range(0,2) what does this 2 mean, are they the number of keys?

Comment: Thank you. Also, I am trying to edit your code I want to generalise to say "i" unique keys, then I am getting:
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. I have mentioned the code in edit

Comment: I cannot tell you without seeing your code. But as you speak I understand what you exactly want to do. Let's edit the answer again

Comment: I have updated my post with your answer.Trying to generalise to n unique keys

Comment: I have updated the answer. What do you think? Is that what you wanted to do?